# In standard algorithms, why are some template parameters rvalue references while others are not?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

For example, let's take a look at the signature of `std::reduce()`:

```cpp
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIt, class T, class BinaryOp >
T reduce( ExecutionPolicy&& policy,
          ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, T init, BinaryOp binary_op );
```

The only parameter with `&&` is `policy`, while the other parameters are supposed to be copied by value. I would understand if all the parameters were forward references, because I could imagine a heavy custom-made iterator that is hard to copy, as well as the initial value or functor of a big type. But why does only the execution policy have `&&`?

Comment: `ExecutionPolicy&&` is a universal / forwarding reference

Comment: History, probably. Execution policies were added at a time when && was available. Most of the algorithms are from an earlier standard, were iterators were supposed to be cheap to copy. And the value is used (modified), so has to be copied anyway.

Comment: @BoP, yeah, I got it about the initial value, but speaking about history, std::reduce itself was also added when && was available. Maybe in this case they just decided to follow the pattern of other algoritms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators are always assumed to be reasonably inexpensive to copy. Algorithms are given wide latitude to copy iterators as much as they see fit (though I believe C++23 adds the ability to make move-only iterators, so for algorithms that can work with them, they are only allowed to move them), and many implementations take advantage of that. So using an iterator type that is "hard to copy" would always pose problems.

The same goes for callable objects. These are presumed to be fairly trivial in size and contents, with algorithms being able to copy them as they see fit.

`reduce` is going to call `binary_op` with two `T` values and assign this to its internal `T`. That's going to perform at least one copy. And it will do this N-1 times, where N is the number of elements in the sequence. Then it's going to return that value, also by value.

So one more copy won't be noticed.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have sence. What about the execution policy, do we really need && there?

Comment: Minor point: `reduce` is going to call `binary_op` with two arguments of type `ForwardIt::value_type`. Often that's the same as `T`, but it doesn't have to be. And that's a trap for beginners, who call the function on a container of floating-point values but pass `0` as `init`, and the result of `binary_op` gets truncated to an integer value.